# How have a cursive font in HTML, I want it to look handwritten?

Tags: html, fonts, font-family

```
<p font-family = "">John Smith <p>
```

I want the above to look like a handwritten signature any font that are in cursive for HTML that work?

Comment: Choose one from https://www.fontspace.com/
Install it and good luck!

Comment: how do I add fontspace file to html?

Comment: Wow, too late I guess. Anyway, it's pretty easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using google fonts (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Great+Vibes). You can use any font by changing the links from the header.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onload="print()"  lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cars</title>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Great+Vibes&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body >

    <p class="handwritten">John Smith <p>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
.handwritten {
    font-family: Great Vibes;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to look for a source at: https://fonts.google.com/
then follow the instructions to use it, in your css you need a font-family: 'font-name', type;
I leave you an example of use:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cedarville+Cursive&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
.p1 {
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive', cursive;
}

.p2 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="p1">This is a paragraph, shown in the Times New Roman font.</p>
<p class="p2">This is a paragraph, shown in the Arial font.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

additionally I recommend you to read the complete css documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp